# ie6 <img> in <span> changes line height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

There is a little part of code

```
<span class="breadcrumbs pathway">
<a href="somewhere.html" class="pathway">
    link
</a>
<img src="/customs/images/M_images/arrow.png" alt="" />
Архив
</span>
```

And the problem is that the image height is less than font-size, ant the line, that contains  becomes thiner.

Tried to add `zoom:1;`, `display:inline-block` or `inline` with no result

This thing happens only in ie6

**UPD**

Well, thank you all, guys. I have found a solution to set img styles to `display:inline-block;` and add a `padding-top:0.5em`

Comment: set different css like: `img{width:100px;height:100px;border:0;etc..}`

Comment: the image is 9x9px, if i set `width` and `height` as 9px, then there is no positive (nor negative) effect, and if i set it, for example 1.5em, then it streches baldy

Comment: Is your `<span>` a fixed height? Try setting it to `display: block;` to retain the height. 

You might just be wasting your time testing for IE6 though - http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: every time i ask about ie6 here i have to say, that it is not my privelege.
And span can contain several lines, so it is not fixed height

Comment: can you create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://www.theie6countdown.com/default.aspx

Comment: Gotta love IE6. 99% of the effort for 1% of the audience.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

@M2_ I had also faced the same problem. Try adding **reset.css** which will reset all the IE styles that browser has by default and you will find [here](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) before adding your custom css files. Also create an **IE-Only** Stylesheet, which will target specifically to IE and for that you can refer [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/). Hope this will help you.

Comment: that was long ago, but I think it would help someone

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to assign `vertical-align: middle;` to the image?

Comment: This wouldn't affect the overall height of the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `line-height` of `<span class="bread-crums pathway">` same heigth as the image.

Ie. if the image has 22px

```
.breadcrumbs{_line-height:22px}
```

Comment: well, the image is 9px height, so it is not good to set line-height so small, but it will work surely

Comment: the line would be too thin, if i'll use the image height as the value

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I don't have an IE6 available to test, but have you tried to

- set the padding and margin to 0?  `style="padding: 0; margin:0"`
- set the height of the image? `style="height: 4px"`
- set the border of the image? `style="border: none"` or `style="border: 0"`